# Linux fgrep how to extract "only_words_in_my_language" from a big "MIXED_WORDS" file?

Tags: linux

I want something to extract "only_words_in_my_language" from a big "MIXED_WORDS" file and for that i used the syntax bellow but with poor results:

```
fgrep -w -f "only_words_in_my_language.txt" "MIXED_WORDS_from_all_over_the_world" > extracted_word_of_my_country_only.txt
```

That's why i'm thinking mmmm.. to ''MATCH'' the entire WORD,for better results
For example this is a WORD in my language:

Maimuta - 7 letters lenght,if i match the entire word the results could be:

```
maimuta@123
maimuta2016!
Maimuta01!
maimuta@123456
```

if i match 6 letter the res. could be:

```
maimut
maimutoi1
Maimutareala01!
```

So my question is how to do that??how to match the entire word or or all but not the last one?
A regex or something for linux please
thank you
Godluck to all!!

Comment: You're nearly there, but `grep` and its derivatives report the whole line when a match is found. You need to add the `-o` option, so that only the matched words will be listed. The `-w` option already eliminates most of your examples. You may also want to add the `-i` option.

Comment: ok i want the whole word MATCH so must look like this?: fgrep -o -i  etc...??? and if i want to match the whole word but not the last one?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "but not the last one". You can combine the options: `fgrep -iowf ...`, but defining separately is OK.

Comment: i mean for example take this word: Maimuta - 7 letters lenght i want to match only first 6 letters or Accelerat - 9 lenght i want match only 8 letters and not the last letter

Comment: and to match the entire word? fgrep -io ?

Comment: i used a mix file ( 64 mb) and grep says: Memory Exhausted

Comment: then i used 20 mb and i receievd same message: Memory Exhausted now i will try with 10 mb mm let's see !!!

Comment: In that case, I'm guessing that the way `grep` works is by building a run string from the contents of the pattern file and, if this is too large, you will run out of memory. The only work-round I can think of is to loop through each entry in the search file, but this will be comparatively slow: `while read w; do fgrep -owe "$w" search_file; done <word_file`; also, the order of the output will be different, but you can use the normal `grep` and regular expressions to get the exact match you want, eg `... grep -iowe "$w." ...`, if I understand your requirement.

Comment: This dones't work...maybe i made soeme mistakes:  grep -iowe "$w."  "my_lang_dict.txt"  "mixed_words" > final-words.txt

Comment: That's not what I intended: I didn't think I had to spell it out, but what I meant was `while read w; do grep -iowe "$w." search_file; done <word_file >result_file`. I repeat, though, that I am still unsure of what you want.

Comment: 1.I have a hungarian-dictionary(100%hungarian words 900kb) clear? ok 2. i have Mixed_Words.txt 135 MB file (words,passwords,from all over the world),so now i want to compare the whole words from hungaryan-dictionary with mixted_words and extract only the hungarian words

Comment: Imagine ur bulgarian,russian and you want to extract ''only'' the words that are in the language of your country from a big mixed words all over the wordl text file.How u would do that?u need a ''ur country'' dictionary right?and then compare all the words from ur country dictionary with the mixed one and   i think best results are.... when u match the entire word!

Comment: (1) If your dictionary file is 900KB and its contents are converted to run parameters, I would not expect to overflow with this size of file: on my 64-bit Ubuntu, the run string limit is 2MB (`getconf ARG_MAX`). (2) The extraction of words from a file that exist in a dictionary has always been clear, but I still don't understand your comments about last letters.